# Change AND to NAND logic doesn't work in C anymore

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've tried to find an algorithm which...

- ...returns 1 (if x == 2^n) //2^n is "2 to the power of n" not xor.
- ...returns 0 (if x != 2^n && x == 0) //2^n is "2 to the power of n" not xor.

I may assume that my machine works with:

- two's complement,
- 32-bit representation of integers,
- performs right shifts arithmetically,
- unpredictable behavior when shifting an integer by more than the word size.

I'm also only allowed to use the following operators: `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`

This is what I got so far:

```
int isPower2(int x) {
  return ( !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)) )); // But this returns 1 if x == 0.
}
```

To get this code working correctly I changed it to `((x ^ 0) && ( !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)`. But I'm not allowed to use `&&`. So I have to build an `AND` out of `NANDs` using the `~` and `&` operator.

But I know, that I can build every possible GATE with `NANDs` (I only need `~` and `&` for it).

So... `X AND Y` is equal to `(X NAND Y) NAND (X NAND Y)` - [NAND logic](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND-Gatter)

```
X := (x ^ 0)
Y := !(x ^ (x & ~x+1))
```

But changing `((x ^ 0) && ( !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)) ))` into `~(~((x ^ 0) & !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)) ) & ~((x ^ 0) & !(x ^ (x & ~x+1))))` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Edit: I added some extra information, hope my problem is clearer now.

Comment: Why not simply `if(x & -x == x)`?

Comment: What is the question? And for that matter, the goal of your manipulations? The change you described went from very unreadable (and redundant, ^0 does nothing) to completely unfathomable.

Comment: Does 2^n mean 2 to the power of n or 2 xor n?

Comment: You confused bitwise and with logical and.

Comment: Does this algorithm should work like this. Return 1 if x is power of 2. Return 0 if is NOT power of 2 OR x is equal 0?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: I'm not allowed to use if ... only bitwise operators.

Comment: @tk4muffin Then `return (x & x == x);`

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Welll now the program tells me, that 3 is a power of 2. Don't even understand why that code should work ...
((x ^ 0) && ( !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)) )) this method works perfect. But I'm not allowed to use the "&&" operator. So I want to use NANDs for that. Somehow the conversion from X && Y -> (X NAND Y) NAND (X NAND Y) doesn't work... :/

PS. I am ONLY allowed to use these operators AT ALL: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

Not == or && or != or even ||

Comment: @YannVernier: X == Y is equivalent to !(x-y) which is equivalent to !(x ^ 0). There for must X != Y be equivalent to (x-y) which is equivalent to (x ^ 0).

This means: Only if X is a positive number (X > 0) the solution can we 1. Otherwise we got negative number or 0. These numbers can't be a power of two.

Comment: @tk4muffin `x ^ 0` is just `x`, `!(x-y)` is equivalent to `!(x^y)`

Comment: @harold: Okay, I have to find the correct equivalent to the != expression with the given bitwise operators then?

Comment: @tk4muffin maybe `!!(x^y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is terrible written but quite interesting
Try this

```
int isPower2(int x) {
  return !(x^(x&~x+1))&!!x;
}
```

More readable version + explanation

```
int isPower2(int x) {
  return 
  (!(
     x^(
        x&((~x)+1) 
       )
  )) 
  & 
  (!!x);
}
```

This code bases on fact that powers of 2 have single `1` in binary representation

`x&((~x)+1)` - will give `x` if `x` is power of 2 or 1 otherwise

```
1 (0001) -> 0001 & (1110+1) -> 0001 & 1111 -> 0001
2 (0010) -> 0010 & (1101+1) -> 0010 & 1110 -> 0010
3 (0011) -> 0011 & (1100+1) -> 0011 & 1101 -> 0001
4 (0100) -> 0100 & (1011+1) -> 0100 & 1110 -> 0100
5 (0101) -> 0101 & (1010+1) -> 0101 & 1011 -> 0001
```

We XOR the result with `x`, since we got `x` for powers of 2 and `1` we get here `0` only for powers of 2.

Later we logically invert result giving us `1` for powers of 2.

To eliminate `0` case we AND with twice logically inverted `x`

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to at least parse a few of the expressions out here. First we have `!(x ^ (x & ~x+1)) )`. The right hand side of the inner & is the definition of a negation in two's complement. For that to have a common bit set with the original value, it must have been carried there in the addition, which means all the less significant bits were 0 before the complement. In effect this finds the least significant bit that was set in x. The ^ (exclusive or) operator then toggles any bit that was set to begin with; if the bit we found was the only one in there, the result is 0. However, it is also 0 if the input was 0, as no bit was ever found set. The logical not (!) thus produces `x==0 || isPowerOf2(x)`. That's what the comment notes; the intent is apparently to remove the case of `x==0`.

That is the function of the change `((x ^ 0) && ( !(x ^ (x & ~x+1)`. The new part checks that any bit was set in x in the first place. `x^0` is equal to x for any x, so the new xor has no effect, but `&&` is a logical operator and therefore does not care which particular bits are set. However, all logical operators except `!` are excluded for this exercise.

The complex attempt at converting `x&&y` into `(x nand y) nand (x nand y)` misses the point that the problem is with bitwise versus logical operators. The `!` present in the expression produces only 1 or 0, destroying the information of which higher bits were set; therefore it doesn't line up with x anymore. In fact `!` is the only operator in our allowed set with this reduction property.

There is an alternate method to produce a reduction with the allowed operators, hinted at in the notes on word width and shift behaviour; you can construct a wide bitwise operation by repeated shifting to line up all bits. While useful if you want to build a parity function or similar, this requires many operations and is error-prone to type out.

If we know the operands are only 0 or 1, the effects of bitwise or logical operators except for complement is equivalent. Since ! does produce those values, we can convert `x&&y` into `!!x & !!y` (ignoring the shortcutting, since we're not dealing with side effects). In this case we already had a ! on the right side, so we can remove two !s.

Comment: Well I didn't mentioned that before, but the MAX allowed operations is set to 16.